# No enterprise was found for the given id

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I have a valid Organization created at `https://play.google.com/work`. When I use the Organization ID available here as Enterprise Id for API calls avaialbe at `https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/androidenterprise/v1/` , I am always getting below response.

```
404

cache-control: private, max-age=0 content-encoding: gzip content-length: 175 content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 date: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 07:47:15 GMT expires: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 07:47:15 GMT server: GSE vary: Origin, X-Origin

{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "No enterprise was found for the given id.", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "enterpriseId" } ], "code": 404, "message": "No enterprise was found for the given id." } }
```

Note: OAuth 2.0 Authorization is on.

Answer (score 0):

This error could arise when the enterprise has already been deleted from Google console (https://play.google.com/work). You can navigate to above URL and in admin settings you can view your enterprise.